# How can I convert datetime stamp in jQuery of a Highchart to get the correct format in json?

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts, utc

To start with I must confess I have not so good knowledge of jQuery and Json. 
Basically my json encode reads like this ["2013-06-18 09:42:30",6.21],["2013-06-18 09:44:30",6.57],["2013-06-18 10:01:49",6.61],......these are the results of battery voltage in given date and time which keeps updating. There are hundreds of records. 
I know this time stamp is not valid while plotting the graph so Yesterday I was trying to tweak the jQuery in jSfiddle to get result and convert it into a chart.
While working in Jsfiddle it said my code is fine but I am getting a blank container area.

Can anyone please guide me on how to convert the datetime stamp in UTC so that a graph can be plotted.

The jQuery which I was tweaking looks like this:

```
    var chart;

    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }},
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     dateTimeLabelFormats: {
     month: '%e. %b',
     year: '%b'
     }
  },
  yAxis: {
     title: {
        text: 'Battery Voltage'
     },
     plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
     }]
  },
  tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
          Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M:%S', this.x) +' : '+ this.y +" V";
      }
  },

series: [{
     name: 'Battery Volatge',
     data: []
    }]
});



function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);

        chart.series[0].setData(data);

    },
    cache: false
});
}
```

and my PHP looks like this:

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/json");

     $dbc = mysql_connect('xxxxx','xxxxx','xxxxx') or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('xxxxx',$dbc) or die(mysql_error());

       $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM Station_State");
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

      $SQL = "SELECT ss_Stamp,ss_BatteryStatus FROM Station_State WHERE Station_State_Index > 371298 AND ss_Station_idx = 34 ORDER BY ss_Stamp";

      $result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn?t execute query.".mysql_error());

      $i=0;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

     $row[ss_BatteryStatus] = (float) $row[ss_BatteryStatus];

$rows[$i]=array($row[ss_Stamp],$row[ss_BatteryStatus]);

$i++;
  }

     echo json_encode($rows);


 ?>
```

It is probably a basic question but I am still learning so any advice will be appreciated. Do let me know if you need any more information or anything I mentioned sounds vague.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simple preprocess your data. Before setting data loop through all points, and convert that string to timestamp, for example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){ 
    data[i][0] = new Date(data[i][0]).getTime();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paweł. I just wanted to know if this bit of code should be written before the function requestdata to pre process it?and if you can be kind enough can you also please answer if having hundreds of records can be another problem for the chart not being displayed?

Comment: If your data is in that format: `["2013-06-18 09:42:30",6.21],` - no, it should work fine as long as you don't want to display 10000 points in a chart of width 100px. Add this snippet before: `chart.series[0].setData(data);`.

Comment: I added your snippet of code before chart.series[0].setData(data); but it is not showing any result.

Comment: Is there any other info you need to confirm what I have done is right and not making any silly mistakes anywhere. I will be grateful if you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? Are you sure that your JSON looks in that way?

Comment: I am using notepad++ and have uploaded the files using FTP. So I do not have a console to be honest. I am getting a blank page in the container part of the page. It is not showing anything.

Comment: The json link is utils.meteovue.co.uk/data.php and the website is utils.meteovue.co.uk/home.php. It is the battery graph link which I am interested in.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? If not install it. Then Open you site and go to:  Options -> Tools -> Javascript Console. Now you have console :) Then you will see error with number. Click on it. You will see that line: `showInLegend = false,` What do you think is wrong with that line? There is `=` while should be `:`.  Also in 69line you have an error. It's an extra comma, remove it. After that, let me know if this working :)

Comment: ohhh sorry. I can be a bit slow at times haha. I do know the Javascript console in google chrome. That is how I started learning Javascript in the first place.

Comment: I made the changes you pointed out. Although there is another error of "Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13 ". Although I checked again and again the div id is container and render to is container as well. I am trying to sort this out.

Comment: Pack your code into `$(function() { /* create chart here */ })()`. Otherwise not full DOM is loaded.

Comment: Ahh. Got it. Thank you so much mna. You have been a right Legend. Thanks again.

Comment: my data from php is `["Date.UTC(2014, 7, 16)", 10]` how do i get rid of the quotes. i believe they are causing the problem.

Comment: my php is `$datetime1 = date('Y, n, j', $dates +  $startdate); 
    $datetime2 = 'Date.UTC('.$datetime1.')'; 
    $lookupprocesspercentdate[] = array($datetime2,$percenttotal);`

Comment: Can't you just pass that value as timestamp (in ms)? Instead of Date.UTC().

Answer (score 0):

Posting Code which works perfectly. The only problem is the a window pops up with encoded data.
 jQuery code:

```
$(function () {

$(document).ready(function() {
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: false
        }
    });
var chart;

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        borderwidth: 0,
        events: {
            load: requestData
        }},
        title: {
            text: 'Battery Graph'
            },
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     dateTimeLabelFormats: {
     month: '%e. %b',
     year: '%b'
     }
  },
  yAxis: {
     title: {
        text: 'Battery Performance Voltage'
     },
     plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
     }]
  },
  tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
          Highcharts.dateFormat('%a %d %b %H:%M:%S', this.x) +' : '+ this.y +" V";
      }
  },

series: [{
     showInLegend: false,
     name: 'Time vs Volatge',
     data: []
    }]
});


function requestData() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'bdata.php',
    datatype: "json",

    success: function(data) {

        alert(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){ 
       data[i][0] = new Date(data[i][0]).getTime();
       }

       chart.series[0].setData(data);

    },

    cache: false
});
};
});

});
```

My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/json");

 $dbc = mysql_connect('xxxx','xxxx','xxxx') or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db('xxxx',$dbc) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM xxxx");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);

$SQL = "SELECT ss_Stamp,ss_BatteryStatus FROM Station_State WHERE Station_State_Index >  377708 AND ss_Station_idx = 34 ORDER BY ss_Stamp";

$result = mysql_query( $SQL ) or die("Couldn?t execute query.".mysql_error());


$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

$row[ss_BatteryStatus] = (float) $row[ss_BatteryStatus];

$rows[$i]=array($row[ss_Stamp],$row[ss_BatteryStatus]);

$i++;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Thank you Pawel. You have been great help.